# Maven compiler plugin isn't calling javac

Tags: java, maven

Running Maven from inside Eclipse or from command line, it does not run javac.  All test and main sources are in default paths src/main/java, src/test/java, src/main/resources, nothing is custom.

It used to compile as well as run my tests, then at some point it just stopped.  Eclipse still compiles the classes if I do project clean, but Maven by itself compiles nothing, and then tests nothing as it also doesn't compile the tests.  I have tried forcing includes of **/*.java (which should be redundant), but did nothing.

Running Maven with -X, it builds the classpath etc, then I see this (I assume here I would see it compile something):

```
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 47 source files to E:\eclipse\osm-test-tool-java\Bell\target\classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
```

After some investigation, I discovered that it was this in my POM file that is causing the issue:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bell</groupId>
    <artifactId>BigDependencies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If I take the Maven classpath and compile with this, using javac directly with -X (verbose), it does not compile the classes.  If I remove the jar above, it compiles (fails because of missing artifacts, but at least it tries). What is this dependency? I have a big shaded jar of all of my external dependencies, the goal being to deploy it once, then be able to do application updates by deploying a much smaller jar. No idea why the shaded jar is making the compiler not function; I'm trying to find a way around it.

Comment: Please show the full pom file and best would be having an example project which shows the behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

After some more research on shading jars, I made the executive decision to stop using a shaded dependency jar; instead made an assembly step that puts all dependent jars in a libs directory and just deploy the libs directory once (whenever it changes, which is rare) and deploy the small app jar alongside it.  Presto, everything works.
Moral of the story is avoid shaded jars, they are fraught with problems (stripping out conflicting manifest information, class loader issues, multiple version conflicts, shading other shaded jars....)